# Can I customize the tag when finishing a git-flow release

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using the `git-flow-avh` version of the tool. We'd like name the release branch differently that the tag. We'd like the branch name to match our release cycle (`sprint-123`), but the tag should be `production_<YYYYMMDDHHMMSS>` with a timestamp.

I see a command line options to suppress tagging and to customize the message, but nothing to override the tag name.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can with a work around.

By default you can't change the tag, but if you finish a release without a tag you could use the hook `pre-flow-release-finish` and tag in that script.

What you need to do is tag the branch from which the release is created, usually `develop` and then tag.

Example script, the script actually gets the branch from which the release is started (BASE_BRANCH)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Runs before git flow release finish
#
# Positional arguments:
# $1    The version (including the version prefix)
# $2    The origin remote
# $3    The full branch name (including the release prefix)
#
# The following variables are available as they are exported by git-flow:
#
# MASTER_BRANCH - The branch defined as Master
# DEVELOP_BRANCH - The branch defined as Develop
#
VERSION=$1
ORIGIN=$2
BRANCH=$3

# Implement your script here.
BASE_BRANCH=$(git config --local --get "gitflow.branch.$3.base")
BASE_BRANCH=${BASE_BRANCH:-$DEVELOP_BRANCH}
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
git checkout $BASE_BRANCH
git tag "production_"$T
git checkout $3

# To terminate the git-flow action, return a non-zero exit code.
exit 0
```

Comment: Is there any way now (updated?) to add something scripty to the `[gitflow "prefix"]` setting like a regular git-alias? e.g. `versiontag = r/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`

Comment: It looks like git-flow hooks can react on parameters but can't change them, don't they?

Comment: I actually never tried, depending on the shell you use it might just be possible.